# Excel Unmerge adding unwanted data in new cells

Tags: excel, excel-365

I have a large excel file with lots of merged rows. I want to unmerge the merged cells in the entire sheet. However when I do the Unmerge, excel is adding default values (based on the value from previously merged cell) in the new cells instead of blank values. Please see below.

**I DON'T WANT THIS**
[image]

**I WANT THIS**
[image]

I expect the default behaviour to be adding blank values, but for some weird reason excel is adding the values which is a huge problem for me and I don't see a way to stop this.

I got this file from someone and I don't know if any settings causing this behaviour. If I take a new file and create a new merged cell and unmerge it, it is not adding unnecessary values it is just adding blank values as expected. But I want this behaviour with the file I'm working with.
It has got thousands of rows and I really need this working. please help.
Thanks

UPDATE:
I have tried exporting as CSV, Copy and Paste only Values to new sheet but everytime it adds its own values as shown below.

[image]
**Unwanted values highlighted, don't know where excel getting
these values from and why? so frustrating.**

Comment: Try Copy and Paste Values only on another sheet.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that please see my comments

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

- Select `B1` (or really `B1:B4`)
- Unmerge
- Merge
- Unmerge

The original merged area was created by either using the Format Painter or the `PasteSpecial Formats` routine from some area on the worksheet that had four cells in a column merged, to B1:B4. This method of creating a merged area does NOT erase the contents of the merged cells below the upper left cell.

Comment: Thanks @Ron-Rosenfeld for the helpful answer. I could do that, it worked, however I have hundreds of merged cells in the sheet and I don't think this works if I select the entire sheet. I agree it is to do with the way the original file was created. I don't see this as the default behaviour if I create a new sheet with merged cells. Thanks again.

Comment: @MSBI-Geek With many merged areas, I'd suggest a VBA macro to process the sheet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was thinking about VBA too. Luckily I found a work around, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. 
 I copied all the data from the excel sheet into Microsoft OneNote and then copied the data back to Excel and then did the Unmerge. this time it worked as expected. 
I believe the hidden references (from Format Painter or Paste Special Formats) were cleared when the data is copied to OneNote. From that point it behaved normal and I don't see any unwanted values in the new cells resulted from the Unmerge.